# Add Subfolder names in Reverse order to Combobox

Tags: vba, filesystems

I have code that loops through a folder and adds all the folder names to a combobox.

```
Dim fsoFile As FileSystemObject: Set fsoFile = New FileSystemObject
Dim fldFile As Object: Set fldFile = fsoFile.GetFolder(NonRPARenewalPath)
    
Dim subFolder As Object: For Each subFolder In fldFile.SubFolders
    Me.cobFolderDate.AddItem subFolder.Name
Next subFolder
```

That code works perfectly fine but now I want to improve upon it.  I want the folders to be added in reverse order (because they are named as the date they are uploaded. e.g.20231103) and I only need the newest 20 folders.  I can figure out how to limit it to the last 20 subfolders and how to do the reverse loop but how do I then add the subfolder name to the combobox.  This is what I tried:

```
Dim i As Integer: For i = UBound(fldFile.SubFolders) To (UBound(fldFile.SubFolders) - 20) Step -1
    Me.cobFolderDate.AddItem fldFile.subFolder(1).Name
Next i
```

Comment: `SubFolders` isn't an array but a `Collection`, so you can use `SubFolders.Count` in place of `UBound(fldFile.SubFolders)`